# How to Filter a List of Objects based on a Condition using another list

Tags: c#, list, linq, .net-core, lambda

I am trying to solve an issue where I want to filter values based on another list of values

List 1:

```
[
  {"Number":"324234","PhoneType":"Cell"},
  {"Number":"645645","PhoneType":"Work"},
  {"Number":"3453453","PhoneType":"phone"},
  {"Number":"342","PhoneType":"fax"}
]
```

List 2:

```
["Work","Cell","phone","Fax"]
```

**Conditions**:
I want to filter list 1 based list 2 values in the given order.

provided list 2 wont be same in all condition, some times it will have only **cell and work** and some time it will have only **work** and sometimes it will have **work,cell,phone and fax**
We don't need to consider phone type fax while we filtering as well as the order in the list 2 will be different each time

**Example:**
List 2 is having work as a first value, if we have phone type work in list 1, then we need to get only that record from list 1, if list 1 does not have work then has to look for phone type cell as its a second value from list 2

I would like to solve this issue using Lamda functions or for each

My Attempt 1:

```
var results = List1.Where((item, index) => list2[index] == "work");
```

Here phone type should be from list 2

My Attempt 2

```
 var primaryPhone = list1?.FirstOrDefault(p => !p.PhoneType.Equals("Fax") && !p.MediaType.Equals("Fax"));
```

The above line returns only the first record by default from List 1

Could some one help me to find the record from list 1 based on list 2 values in the given order

Comment: Are you looking to return only the first matching item, or all of them?

Comment: first matching item @Orion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following filter.

```
var listToFilter = new List<Phone>()
{
    new() { Number = "324234",  PhoneType = "Cell" },
    new() { Number = "645645",  PhoneType = "Work" },
    new() { Number = "3453453", PhoneType = "Phone" },
    new() { Number = "342",     PhoneType = "Fax" }
};

var filterList = new[] { "Work", "Cell", "Phone", "Fax" };

Phone matchingPhone = null;
foreach (var filter in filterList)
{
    matchingPhone = listToFilter.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PhoneType == filter);
    if (matchingPhone is not null)
        break;
};
```

Examples here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/d9pP3k

As a function:

```
private static Phone GetMatchingPhone(IEnumerable<Phone> phones, IEnumerable<string> filters)
{
    foreach (var filter in filters)
    {
        var matchingPhone = phones.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PhoneType == filter);
        if (matchingPhone is not null)
            return matchingPhone;
    };

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first we need some C# classes, holding your desired information:

```
public record PhoneEntry(string Number, PhoneType PhoneType);

public enum PhoneType
{
    Cell,
    Work,
    Phone,
    Fax
}
```

At next, we need a comparer that takes a list of the desired order as input:

```
public class PhoneTypeComparer : IComparer<PhoneType>
{
    private readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<PhoneType, int> ordering;

    public PhoneTypeComparer(IReadOnlyCollection<PhoneType> ordering)
    {
        this.ordering = ordering
            .Select((x, i) => (x, i))
            .ToDictionary(x => x.x, x => x.i);
    }
    public int Compare(PhoneType x, PhoneType y)
    {
        if (x == y)
            return 0;

        if (!ordering.TryGetValue(x, out int xWeight))
            xWeight = 1_000_000;

        if (!ordering.TryGetValue(y, out int yWeight))
            yWeight = 1_000_000;

        return xWeight - yWeight;
    }
}
```

Then let's deserialize your given data into the new classes:

```
var jsonEntries = """
    [
        {"Number":"324234","PhoneType":"Cell"},
        {"Number":"645645","PhoneType":"Work"},
        {"Number":"3453453","PhoneType":"phone"},
        {"Number":"342","PhoneType":"fax"}
    ]
    """;

var jsonFilter = """
    ["Cell","Work","phone","Fax"]
    """;

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter() }
};
var entries = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PhoneEntry[]>(jsonEntries, options)
    ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(jsonEntries));
var filter = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PhoneType[]>(jsonFilter, options)
    ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(jsonFilter));
```

Then we need to create a comparer from the filter and apply it on the given list to sort it:

```
var comparer = new PhoneTypeComparer(filter);
var ordered = entries
    .OrderBy(entry => entry.PhoneType, comparer)
    .ToList();
```

And finally print out the new ordering:

```
foreach (var entry in ordered)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{entry.PhoneType}: {entry.Number}");
}
```

If you need to filter only on the defined values and picking the first, you have to sort them out and pick the first:

```
var desired = entries
    .Join(filter, entry => entry.PhoneType, type => type, (entry, type) => entry)
    .OrderBy(entry => entry.PhoneType, comparer)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```